# Is it possible to see a log or history of previous iTerm2 sessions?

Tags: console, iterm2, iterm

Is there a log of recent terminal sessions at all? Or anyway I can see what was written to console before I last quit?

Answer (score 40):

There is the option to save a log of your session to a file, however, by default this isn't done.

To activate the session logs, go to iTerm2 Preferences (⌘,), select the "Profiles" tab, then the "Session" tab. Under "Miscellaneous" you can specify a folder where log files for your sessions shall be saved in the future.

[image: screenshot with the preferences you need to adapt]

Edit:

These session logs can become quite big, so you might want to have a look from time to time to not clutter your drive.

Comment: Anyone else having an issue retrieving the logs? mine is scattered with random posix characters and memory addresses

Comment: @Jonathan if you open a terminal and run `cat logfile.log` it should print the recorded session into your terminal.

Comment: Is there a way to open these in an editor like sublime?

Comment: @DanielKobe go to the folder specified on that settings panel, and open them with any text editor you like.

Comment: This option says log session input into files ? Does it include the output of the commands we run as well on the ssh sessions like some bash command outputs that gets printed on the terminal